# cold brew coffee ... cold brew wort

Tags: beer, brewing, wort

I love coffee.
I love it light(Blonde) and dark.  I love it with creamer and (sugar-free) sweetener.

One kind of coffee I like is "cold brewed coffee".
Instead of steeping in boiling water for a few minutes, it is soaked in cold water for a few hours.
It gets all the caffeine.
It does not extract the acid, and it has a much mellower taste.

In chemistry you can get chemical/molecular diffusion at a much lower temperature as long as you let the process continue for a longer (or much longer) time.

So I had this thought....
Can I make a wort using the cold brewing, then boil it after?

What does it do to the beer? Has it been done before; if so what is it called?

I think chemistry says the sugars can be extracted at a lower temperature, and while it might take longer, it can change the nature of the flavors extracted, including acidity.

Some references:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7404565/
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0924224419305692
- https://www.kerry.com/insights/kerrydigest/2018/what-science-tells-us-about-making-the-best-tasting-cold-brew-coffee.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean 'wort' rather than 'wart', the answer is no.

You need to bring your malt to mashing temperature (typically between 60 and 70 degrees Celsius) in order to activate the enzymes that turn starch into fermentable sugars. Then you need the heat of the boil to congeal proteins (known as hot break),and to isomerize the hops' alpha acids without which you would not get any bitterness.

None of that can happen at room temperature.